# Possible wood defect in roof space

Tags: wood, attic

Recently purchased house in Western Australia, 20 years old.
Roofspace wood has several pieces of timber with black charred looked defects. All appears structural sound… I just want to know what the defects are and if it will become a problem. [image: worst defect pictured]

[image]

Comment: They look more like tar/sap, than fungus/mold.  Imagine if you used a piece of wood/tool it will be sticky, instead of damp/powdery.

Answer (score 1):

First one is a pitch pocket, second one is a knot. What looks like charring is actually dried tree sap, barring the unusual case of a tree that lived though a fire and grew more after that.

Both come from how the tree grew. Neither will get worse, they just are there.

A timber without the defects would be stronger, but timber grading and load tables related to timber grading take defects into account.

Comment: The knots *are* quite sizable compared to the cross section, more than a third. If this is a through and through (is it?), it might be a problem if the variable loads use up loadbearing capacity safety. I'd expect it to be okay considering it's only 20 years old, but I'd feel better to have this one checked out (again, whichever fixed loads are on it, and which variable loads are common for your locale).

Comment: It hasn't failed in 20 years, which strongly suggests it's adequate for the job it's doing.

Comment: I'm concerned about weather extremes, we're getting more and more of these. Hence safety margins :)

Comment: I doubt he'll get much snow load in Western Australia so it'll surely be OK. (If he does, however, we will all be in for _interesting_ times!)

Comment: I suppose from a bushfire perspective both the knot and the structural wood have equally bad properties :x